# Error in SQL Server of join two tables with case (when...end):

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Update: I get an error when join two tables with case (when..end):

tmp1:

```
A       B   C
---------------
1       1   1
NULL    1   2
NULL    2   1
2       2   2
```

tmp2:

```
A   B   C   D
---------------
1   1   1   X
2   1   1   Y
1   1   2   Z
2   1   2   X
1   2   1   Y
2   2   1   Z
1   2   2   X
2   2   2   Z
```

I want to join two tables and get tmp1.* + tmp2.D. If tmp1.A is not null, use TMP1.A = TMP2.A, TMP1.B = TMP2.B, AND  TMP1.C = TMP2.C to join.
If tmp1.A is null, set tmp1.A = [MIN(TMP2.A) OVER (PARTITION BY TMP2.B, TMP2.C)] and then join. Here is the results what I want:

```
A       B   C     D
-------------------
1       1   1     X
1       1   2     Z   
1       2   1     Y
2       2   2     Y
```

The following is my codes, I got the error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'END'

Actually I am not sure how to join them correctly? Any suggestion will be appreciate!

```
SELECT TMP1.*, TMP2.D
FROM TMP1
LEFT JOIN TMP2 ON CASE
                     WHEN TMP1.A IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 'TMP1.A = TMP2.A AND  TMP1.B = TMP2.B AND TMP1.C = TMP2.C'
                     WHEN TMP1.A IS NULL
                        THEN 'TMP1.A = MIN(TMP2.A) OVER (PARTITION BY TMP2.B, TMP2.C)
                       AND  TMP1.B = TMP2.B
                       AND  TMP1.C = TMP2.C' 
             END
```

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns **one, atomic value** - it's not capable of returning fragments of code to be executed. You need to fundamentally rewrite your query

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the single quotes are typos or not.  If they are intentional, then they are just strings and have nothing to do with the logic being processed (and will generate a syntax error without a comparison of some sort after the `case` expression)

Assuming the strings represent the logic you do want, you can express the logic without a `case` expression, using just boolean logic:

```
SELECT TMP1.*, TMP2.D
FROM TMP1 LEFT JOIN
     TMP2
     ON (TMP1.A IS NOT NULL AND TMP1.A = TMP2.A AND TMP1.B = TMP2.B AND
         TMP1.C = TMP2.C
        ) OR
        (TMP1.A IS NULL AND TMP1.A = MIN(TMP2.A) OVER (PARTITION BY TMP2.B, TMP2.C) AND
         TMP1.B = TMP2.B AND TMP1.C = TMP2.C
        )
```

I will don't think this will work, because the window function is not allowed in an `ON` clause.  Perhaps this expresses what you intend:

```
SELECT TMP1.*, TMP2.D
FROM TMP1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT TMP2.*,
             MIN(TMP2.A) OVER (PARTITION BY TMP2.B, TMP2.C) as MIN_A
      FROM TMP2
     ) TMP2
     ON (TMP1.A IS NOT NULL AND TMP1.A = TMP2.A AND TMP1.B = TMP2.B AND
         TMP1.C = TMP2.C
        ) OR
        (TMP1.A IS NULL AND TMP1.A = TMP2.MIN_A AND
         TMP1.B = TMP2.B AND TMP1.C = TMP2.C
        )
```

Of course, the second part of the boolean expression will always be treated as `FALSE` (technically it evaluates as `NULL`) because `TMP1.A` is NULL and yet you are trying to compare it to something else.

These are very arcane conditions.  I wonder if they are really needed.  Alternative ways to implement the logic are appropriate for *another* question, with a better explanation of what you are doing, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @liuzhi316 . . . I did specifically point out that you should ask *another* question.  I think the syntax problem in your original question was addressed by this answer.

Comment: The comments is intentional. I am not sure how to write the case clause. I updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. I found `min(a)` for each `b` and `c` combinations using correlated subquery, then joined with `tmp2` to get final result

```
select
    t.a, t.b, t.c, q.d
from (
    select
        a = isnull(a.a, (select min(b.a) from tmp2 b where a.b = b.b and a.c = b.c))
        , a.b, a.c
    from
        tmp1 a
) t join tmp2 q on t.a = q.a and t.b = q.b and t.c = q.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works well!